# How to properly configure a postfix satellite server with reverse DNS?

Tags: networking, email, dns, postfix, exim

I administrate a network which has a central mail server that sends all mail, and one of our sites uses a relay host to pass on the mail through the main mail server. Lately, we've been running into a lot of problems with email hosts demanding that we properly set up a RDNS, which I've attempted to do for our static IP, but I think I'm misunderstanding how I'm supposed to set it.

Our main site, we'll call "mydomain.net," is the one that handles the mail. It's sent from "mydomain.net" using exim4 configured via WHM. The relay host uses postfix configured in satellite mode, and it accepts emails sent from our backend servers running apache2. We can call this "mysubdomain.mydomain.net." The mail gets routed to the "master" server, which then relays it to the main server that contains exim. The relay server has a public facing IP for the sake of identification, but it doesn't resolve to anything because the server itself is only meant to be communicated with internally. "mysubdomain.mydomain.net" doesn't resolve to that IP because it routes to our load-balancer, which routes to our frontend varnish servers. Is it viable to have this internal-only server be the relay? Do I need to install relays on the frontend servers instead? What would I even set the RDNS to for the IP that identifies the relay?

I've tried the hostname of the relay and the fqdn of the mail server (mail.mydomain.net), but I still seem to get some email providers blocking it. I'm just not sure what to check next.

And to clarify: emails do indeed send. I can even send them from the CLI. It's just that some providers wrongfully mark them as spam. This issue doesn't happen for emails sent from the sites hosted via the WHM server, which directly accepts the emails from the hosted sites and sends them.